# My button or text keeps duplicating every time I hit save?

Tags: jquery, duplicates, each

**Update to my question towards bottom :-)**

I have a table where I can edit a table that updates using `Ajax`. Though I'm using `jQuery` to edit particular things I require, as seen below.

The main cause of issue is that every time I hit a button that is used to save my edited records for the table it adds an additional 'View Notes' or 'No Notes' `button`?

Is there anyway to stop duplicates from appearing?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $(".notescontainer").each(function(){

     if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {

         $(this).parent().find('.view-notes').addClass("vw-none");
         $(this).parent().find('.lanotes').prepend('No Notes').addClass('nonotes');

      } else {

          var lanotes = $('.lanotes');
          var viewnotes = $('<button class="view-notes" type="button">View Notes</button>');
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.lanotes').prepend(viewnotes);
          $(this).parent().find('.view-notes').addClass("vw-some");
      }
    });
  });
});
```

I believe the issue is something to do with `.each`? So every time I hit the button that saves the record is it reapplying because of `.each`?

Is there any way to assure that my 'View Notes' and 'No Notes' text and button don't duplicate? That it checks the row that if the `.notescontainer` has no value then it only displays the 'No Notes' text once and same goes with the View Notes.

I hope that is clear? If not I'll try and rephrase.

Thanks in advance. :)

**UPDATE:**

I've been requested to supply a jsfiddle. However, due to the fact my page requires `ajax` calls and multiple `jquery` inserts it's to big to do that. So I'm not sure how else I can share it?

So perhaps I can help myself narrow down the solution by explaining more?

How do I change this bit of code:

```
if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {

    $(this).parent().find('.view-notes').addClass("vw-none");
    $(this).parent().find('.lanotes').prepend('No Notes').addClass('nonotes');
```

To also exclude any buttons for that row that have a class that matches either `vw-none` or `vw-some within`.lanotes`. Here is my attempt:

```
if (!$(this).text().trim().length) {
    $(this).parent().find('.view-notes').addClass("vw-none");

    if(! $(this).parent().find('.view-notes').hasClass("vw-none", "vw-some")) {
        $(this).parent().find('.lanotes').prepend('No Notes').addClass('nonotes');
    }

} else {
```

**What happens**

```
<td id="thenotes" class="lanotes tabledit-view-mode">
    <button class="view-notes vw-some" type="button">View Notes</button>
    <button class="view-notes vw-some" type="button">View Notes</button>
</td>
```

When I hit save on my ajax 'save button' my above code does not check weather an existing button already exists so it just adds the code again. Is there any way above using my jquery to check if a button with either `.vw-none` or `.vw-some` already appears for that table row, if it does then it doesn't load the code for that table row?

Thanks again! :-)

Comment: It would help if you can provide a jsfiddle or code snippet

Comment: We definitely will need the html structur for this one

Answer (score 0):

You should try to add a container to the button/no button and exchange it`s contents instead of prepending it.

Something like this:

```
<td id="thenotes" class="lanotes tabledit-view-mode">
   <span class="button-container"></span>
</td>
```

And then:

```
$(this).parent().find('.lanotes').addClass('nonotes');
$(this).parent().find('.lanotes .button-container').html('No notes');
```

This way your button will not pile endlessly.

P.s: you should not use a id on a element that will repeat itself, like the `thenotes` on your `<td>`